# AWS - find all instances that are running but nobody is connected to them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-athena, amazon-vpc

**Hello!**

I need to find all instances that are currently running, but nobody connected to them via port 22 or 3389 for the past 2 weeks.

I figured I could use *VPC Flowlogs* and *Athena query* to create a list of network interfaces and then eliminate manually all instances with those network interfaces that are not on the list.
It's a tedious work so I am looking for more efficient way to get needed information.

Do you have any ideas how to approach this problem differently?